# SQL query to find: X% of A is attributed to Y% of B

Tags: sql, t-sql, statistics, data-analysis

I have been asked to investigate some statistics in a recruitment database. The figure I have been asked to get is:

> X% of applications go to Y% of jobs

The tables containing application and job information are very simple and the schema looks like so (simplified):

```
create table jobs (jobId int, jobTitle varchar(100))
create table applications (applicationId int, jobId int)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26a7d/1)

I am struggling to visualise what the statistic represents let alone how to word this as a SQL query.

The goal of this is to identify if there are jobs that tend to attract more applications than others and by what magnitude. Is this a common pattern? If so, is there a formal name for it and how can it be written as a T-SQL query?

Comment: You should really show us what the expected output is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen X% of applications and the percentage of jobs they are attributed to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(float,(select COUNT(applicationId) FROM applications WHERE jobId = j.jobId))/(select COUNT(*) FROM applications) * 100) +'% of applications go to ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(1.00 /(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM jobs) * 100)) +'%' AS [OUTPUT] FROM jobs j

Answer (score 0):

As I try to understand this, I figure what it tries to show is that some jobs get more applications than others. For example, consider 100 jobs, where 99 had actually NO applications and the one remaining had all the rest. Then you would say "100% of applications go to 1% of jobs". It is an extreme example, demonstrating one useful bit of evidence.

It is also obvious that "100% of applications go to 100% of jobs".

The most detailed thing you can do is to get the top 1 job, then the top 2 jobs etc until all are included and calculate the application.

I think this will give you all X-Y pairs:

```
select j.jobId,count(*) as appcount
into #a
group by j.jobId
from jobj j 
inner join applications a on j.jobId=a.jobId

declare @sumjobs int =(select count(*) from #a)
declare @sumapps int =(select sum(appcount) from #a)

select
    100*sum(appcount) over (order by appcount ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/@sumapps as X,
    100*sum(1) over (order by appcount ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/@sumjobs as Y
from #a
```

Note that you need to have sql server 2012+ for this to work.
If this does not work, please provide sample data so we can test on them.